# Show how to form a location-scale family $g(x)$ based on $f(x)$ such that $g(x)$ has mean $0$ and variance $1$.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, statistical-inference

Consider a random variable $X$ with the log-normal pdf $f(x) ={1\over \sqrt{2π}}x^{−1}e^{{−0.5 (logx)^2}}$,   $x >0$.

Show how to form a location-scale family $g(x)$ based on $f(x)$ such that $g(x)$ has mean $0$ and variance $1$.

I'm not sure how to go about this. I know that a location-scale family is a family of probability distributions parametrized by a location parameter and a non-negative scale parameter.

Comment: It might be worth starting by finding the mean and variance of $X$

Comment: $E(X)=\sqrt{e}$, $E(X^2)=e^2$, and $Var(X)=e(e-1)$

Comment: Then you want $Y=\dfrac{X-\sqrt{e}}{\sqrt{e(e-1)}}$ and you can use the expressions at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family